# Re-render Widget after column number changes

Tags: plugin-development, dashboard-widgets

Is it possible to automatically re-render a widget after the number of columns is changed? I have a widget that has to be re-rendered/re-executed after the widget columns change and I don't know how to realize it.

I can't just make a javascript event like `$(window).resize()` because I already have this function and check if the client client height changes there because otherwise it would trigger every second for no reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer that works for me at least..
Since I render my widget via Javascript and not via PHP/Twig I can use this

```
$(document).on("click", ".colspan-picker a", function(){
    var container = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
    widgetID = container.data("id");
    sRGoogleAnalyticsRerenderChart(widgetID);
});
```

`.colspan-picker a` is the element for columnchange and its `parent().parent().parent()` has a data-id of the widget container